# Throwing Allies Without Intent to Harm

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, throwing-things

I can't find anything for this on the Internet or in the books. Let's say my (fairly typical Powerhouse) character wants to throw his ally up to the top of a skyscraper to save time climbing stairs. Is there any official ruling on how I would go about doing this? Would the Precise modifier allow me to throw people without harming them? If there's no official ruling, how would you go about house-ruling this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is nothing in the core rules that specifically covers this. I would probably require an "attack roll" by the person doing the throwing to accurately target where they want the person to go with the person doing the landing having to make an Acrobatics check to stick the landing, or maybe an Athletics check to grab on. Just to pick some arbitrary figures, I'd probably say that it's at least a DC 10+Distance Rank to get them there (accounting for that, after 25% of the maximum distance you can throw them, you're at a -2 to hit, and after 50%, you're at -5) and a DC 10+Distance Rank Acrobatics to stick the landing. With the difference in success determining the rank of damage. So if you're throwing your guy to the top of the Empire State Building (1250 feet), that's Rank 6. Assuming that's within 25% of the maximum distance you could throw the guy, you're rolling to hit a DC of 16. Let's say you get a total of 15. They have a roll against DC 16 Acrobatics (untrained) to land safely and they roll a total of 14. Between the two rolls, that's a difference of 3, and so they roll against DC 18 Damage.

Comment: Thanks!


FASTBALL SPECIAL TIME GUYS!